# 'LIKE' Query Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, information-retrieval

I have a problem with like-query in my project.The requirement is 'like' srarch in about 10million name, for example:

---

amy
ford
phil
jedwk
edwords
jones

I want srarch names that have 'edw', the result should be 'jedwk' and 'edwords'.
Just like "select * from table where name like '%edw%'" in sql.

---

Do you have some algorithm can deal this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: is a plain loop to slow? if so, an algorithm probably won't help. you need a *data structure*.

Comment: You are looking for string searching methods? Just google for it or use Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use a variation of **[suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)**, where in addition each leaf in the tree holds a reference to the original string this suffix refer to.

This will allow you to follow the path of the input query on the suffix tree, and from there do a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to get all leaves reachable from this substring. Each leaf will contain the relevant strings - and you just need to extract them.

---

PS Note that most Information Retrieval systems do not allow a 'substring' search, only a 'prefix search' - which is much more easier to implement, using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for example.

Comment: Thanks! I will use this algorithm.